# Fargate cluster with dedicated VPC configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I did not quite understand the configuring of VPC "CIDR block" while creating fargate cluster. Based on the link https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/aws-fargate-metrics/, there is a fleet that runs outside my VPC that has the infrastructure to run my fargate tasks.

What I dont understand if I configure a dedicated VPC for my fargate cluster. How does it connect with dedicated AWS managed  infrastructure for fargate.

I did not find any documentation with some explaination.

Answer (score 0):

After googling for sometime, found this   https://thenewstack.io/aws-fargate-through-the-lens-of-kubernetes/

The author states the VPC configured during fargate cluster creation acts as proxy and requests are fwded to EC2 instance running in VPC owned/managed by AWS. Configuring VPC serves the purpose of controlling the IP range of ENI attached to containers. This is based on my observation, need something more to back it up.